# Cakephp format array with Hash

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to reorganize this array by using Hash utiliti:

```
array( 
'AreaUser' => array(
     (int) 0 => '3',
     (int) 1 => '2'
);
```

into this array:

```
array( 
'AreaUser' => array(
                0 => array(
                    'area_id' => 2
                ),
                1 => array(
                    'area_id' => 3
                )
);
```

Can you help me with it? Is it even possible to achive this with Hash utiliti? This will help me to save data from multiple select.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`Hash::format()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash%3a%3aformat):

```
Hash::format($data, array('AreaUser.{n}.area_id'), '%1$s');
```

Haven't tested it, but it should give you a starting point.

Or you can use [`Hash::extract()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash%3a%3aextract):

```
$area_ids = Hash::extract($data['AreaUser'], '{n}.area_id');
$data['AreaUser'] = $area_ids;
```